# Zina without penetration

Tags: fiqh, punishment, zina

What is the punishment for this? I always heard about what the punishment will be for it, if I penetrate someone, but what if someone just sleeps with the opposite sex (without penetration), how will he/she get punished?

Comment: Then to the best of my knowledge, that is not called "Zina" at all.

Comment: @azam Sleeping with a non-mahram woman in the same bed without any sexual penetration not a Zina?

Comment: I understood in which perspective you are saying like this. But the word 'Zina' is used to mean major zina, more specifically intercourse. If you want to call it Zina, then most probably you could call it "Zina of laying". And Allah knows the best. Jajakallah. @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok

Comment: What is the punishment for it though, am I going to be burnt in molten lava or lead in Jahannam?

Comment: No, this zina, but doesn't require punishment, as there are different types of zina as the prophet said: كُتِبَ عَلَى ابْنِ آدَمَ حَظُّهُ مِنَ الزِّنَا ، الْعَيْنُ تَزْنِي وَزِنَاهَا النَّظَرُ ، وَالْفَمُ يَزْنِي وَزِنَاهُ التَّقْبِيلُ ، وَالْيَدَانِ تَزْنِيَانِ وَزِنَاهُمَا اللَّمْسُ ، وَالرِّجْلُ تَزْنِي وَزِنَاهَا الْمَشْيُ ، وَيُصَدِّقُ ذَلِكَ أَوْ يُكَذِّبُهُ الْفَرْجُ , and the punishment might be as you you said, it is up to Allah to decide anyways, unless you repent sincerely as I said in my answer, then in shaa' Allah you're safe.

Comment: check this one too http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/do-actions-kissing-touching-etc-which-could-lead-to-zina-sex-before-marriag

Comment: @servant Thanks for the link, but I already know that they are minor Zina. I just wanted to know just sleeping and foreplaying (but no penetration involved) with a non-mahram counts as major Zina.

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok, to the best of my knowledge, it is a kind of major sin (although the sin of Zina is more than ...) / Anyhow, an appropriate answer to your practical query would be helpful for ... / Good luck mate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific punishment for this act (sleeping with someone without having intercourse) in the dunia, as punishment was only mentioned for those who commit fornication (intercourse). However, Allah might keep the punishment until the hereafter unless the sinner repents sincerely, as repentance deletes what's before. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

As you have asked   `but what if someone just sleeps with the opposite sex (without penetration)`,It is a great sin and not allowed in Islam ,,one must sincerely repent and do Tawbah.

> .......The food (slaughtered cattle, eatable animals, etc.) of the people of the Scripture (Jews and Christians) is lawful to you and yours is lawful to them. (Lawful to you in marriage) are chaste women from the believers and chaste women from those who were given the Scripture (Jews and Christians) before your time, when you have given their due Mahr (bridal money given by the husband to his wife at the time of marriage), desiring chastity (i.e. taking them in legal wedlock) not committing illegal sexual intercourse, nor taking them as girl-friends.....Quran Al-Maida [5:5](http://tanzil.net/#5:5)

It is not allowed in Islam to make any kind of relationships or hanging around and sleeping with Non Mahram and as the question says if someone just sleeps indicating not sure if may be once or more it could lead to intercourse as well so should stop doing this way of destroying duniya o akhirah.

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah has written the very portion of Zina which a man will indulge in. There will be no escape from it. The **Zina of the eye** is the (lustful) look, the **Zina of the ears** is the listening (to voluptuous songs or talk), the **Zina of the tongue** is (the licentious) speech, the **Zina of the hand** is the (lustful) grip, the **Zina of the feet** is the walking (to the place where he intends to commit Zina), **the heart yearns and desires and the private parts approve all that or disapprove it**."

[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

**So whosoever does good equal to the weight of an atom (or a small ant), shall see it.And whosoever does evil equal to the weight of an atom (or a small ant), shall see it**. Quran 99:7-8

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Don't worry, I know my limits. I just wanted to know what  the punishment is if someone doesn't penetrate a woman, but shares the bed with her. Just wanted to know if it is like major Zina or not.

Comment: ok MashAllah ,,As you have commented above that "am I going to be burnt in molten lava or lead in Jahannam? – so try to ask question like by referring in other form like "is the sinner would burnt in molten lava" ,,may Allah swt protect all.

Comment: check this one http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/do-actions-kissing-touching-etc-which-could-lead-to-zina-sex-before-marriag

Comment: I think this is also a good one: http://islamqa.info/en/81995

Answer (score -1):

The person will go to jahannam for doing anything with a man who they are not lawfully married. It is harram to even talk to a man in islam never mind sleeping with them.

Comment: I agree. In many mazhab you lose your wudu for even shaking hands with non-mahram.  Isa, ibn Meryam said "If you look at another non-mahram lustfully you have already committed zina in your heart.  So forget about touching or laying in bed.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Comment: Who are you to declare that somebody will go to jahannam?