# Does rubbing my private parts with that of a boy amount to zina?

Tags: zina, men-women

I had a boyfriend, but he cheated me by lying.  The problem is that I have kissed him, and we have been intimate.  He rubbed his private parts with that of mine.  Now I feel so guilty.  Is it zina? Can I get married to other person?

Comment: 1) It is important to keep your sins private. 2) Allah will forgive you if He wills. Don't see it as something impossible. 3) I have never heard about anything like this making future marriage forbidden. (hadiths and such: http://islamqa.info/en/3365). Commenting since this answer isn't heavily sourced.

Comment: See also here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/do-actions-kissing-touching-etc-which-could-lead-to-zina-sex-before-marriag?rq=1

Comment: "touching" is not counted as sex, but it's a sin and yyou should ask Allah for forgivness and never do it again. You shouldn't tell about it anybody, as this wasn't zina! So if you do so you -even if you would have committed zina- you'll be regarded as chaste as anybody else and could get married with any chaste man!

Comment: All i can tell you is that if you regret and repent you are considered as chaste as any good man/woman and you can marry any chaste man. Try to forget your former sin and the man who joined you in that sin and replace it with good deeds this would be the best for you! And leave the future of this man and his punishment in the hands of Allah!

Comment: Do Tawba and try not to do it again. If you do it again, do Tawba and try not to do it again. May Allah forgive and guide you. And yes you can get married. Even if you committed Zina, you still can get married. Trust in Allah and ask for his forgiveness, he is the Rahman, The Merciful. Just relax and trust in Him.

Answer (score 5):

Zina is not penetration only. There's different kinds of zina. The zina of eyes, which is looking at things one should not be looking at (porn, etc.), the zina of hand, which is touching that that is not allowed (masurbation, etc.), the zina of tongue, which is talking about all the unlawful sexual stuff one desires and then the zina of the private parts, which is penetration. The last one is the major zina and is punishable by Hadd under Islamic Law-- assuming all the requirements are met.

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Allaah has decreed for every son of Adam his share of zina, which he will inevitably commit. The zina of the eyes is looking, the zina of the tongue is speaking, one may wish and desire, and the private parts confirm that or deny it.”
>
> [Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5889; Muslim, 2657.](http://islamqa.info/en/27259)

You should seek forgiveness from Allah. Try to be fearful of Allah (SWT) both in public and private. Offer the five daily prayers on time. Allah loves those who repent. It's mentioned in Surat Al-Baqara verse number 222:

> ويسالونك عن المحيض قل هو اذى فاعتزلوا النساء في المحيض ولا تقربوهن حتى يطهرن فاذا تطهرن فاتوهن من حيث امركم الله ان الله يحب التوابين ويحب المتطهرين
>
> And they ask you about menstruation. Say, "It is harm, so keep away from wives during menstruation. And do not approach them until they are pure. And when they have purified themselves, then come to them from where Allah has ordained for you. **Indeed, Allah loves those who are constantly repentant and loves those who purify themselves.**"

*emphasis is mine.*

For more information on repentance, please [see this article on repentance.](http://muslimmatters.org/2011/10/06/riyadh-as-saliheen-series-hadith-4-repentance/)

Answer (score 5):

What you did is considered minor sin. In Islam Adultery happens when a penis penetrates the Vagina.

There is no punishment for such actions in Islam, which are forgiven by doing your daily Salah and asking Allah for forgiveness.

There is a similar [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/1314630) about the prophet PBUH for your situation:

> It was narrated from ‘Abdullah bin Mas’ud that a man did something with a woman that was less than adultery; I do not know how far it went, but it was less than adultery. He went to the Prophet (ﷺ) and told him about that. Then Allah revealed the words:
>   “And perform the prayer, at the two ends of the day and in some hours of the night. Verily, the good deeds remove the evil deeds. That is a reminder for the mindful.” [11:114] He said: “O Messenger of Allah, is this only for me?” He said: “It is for everyone who acts upon it.”

Don't get me wrong, what you did is still considered Zina, but the type of Zina that does not come with Punishment (looking at porn, Lesbianism, masturbating, etc..) and erased by asking for forgiveness.

Personally, I would think it is OK to get married without telling your future husband about this issue, since it will cause more harm than good. When Allah covers your sins, you shouldn't broadcast them to anyone.

Comment: Is it a minor sin?

Comment: @Anwar Unless you have a reference that it is, I can't label it a major sin. Hadith itself doesn't require repentance, which doesn't usually work with Major sins.