# Will allah punish me and never forgive me?

Tags: punishment, zina, pregnancy

Will Allah forgive for participating in sexual intercourse without penetration if a person was sincere in their repentance!

Does this count as Zina although penetration did not occur?

What is the best way to repent from such actions and make sure not to fall in them in the future?

Comment: Enough to say that **Allah is the refuge of sinners**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IS THIS ZINA? WILL ALLAH EVER FORGIVE ME FOR THIS?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28927/is-this-zina-will-allah-ever-forgive-me-for-this)

Answer (score 2):

In the Name of Allah, the **Most Gracious**, the **Most Merciful**.

> Will Allah punish me and never forgive me?

Firstly, No one among us can ever speak on Allah's behalf and say that Allah (SWT) will not forgive you for what you've done, there is a hadith in Sahih Muslim that says:

> The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said: “A man
>   said: By Allah, **Allah will not forgive** this person! Allah the Exalted
>   said: Who is he who swore by me that I will not forgive someone? I
>   have forgiven him and nullified your good deeds.”

Secondly, I cannot count the number of verses and ahadith that talk about Allah's forgiveness and mercy, they are far beyond our understanding and imagination.

Finally, what I can advise you is:

- Do not despair of the mercy of Allah (SWT) no matter how much you've sinned. Always seek His forgiveness and mercy.

> Say: O My servants who have transgressed against their own souls,
>   despair not of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins.
>   Truly, He is Most Forgiving, Most Merciful. (Surah az-Zumar 39:53)

- Please do not repent just because you are afraid that you might get pregnant. Repent sincerely to Allah (SWT) and He will not expose you due to his mercy.
- Encourage your partner to repent to Allah (SWT) as well and do your best to abstain from that sin, and try to get married if possible.

Allah knows best!

Comment: I think the best part of your nice answer is: "Do not despair of the mercy of Allah (SWT) no matter how much you've sinned.". Jazak Allah Khaira.